# How to add tags to suitecrm

Tags: suitecrm

New to suitecrm. I need a tag module but can't seem to find anything. 
The goal is to add tags to contants and account and then find them based on those tags. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a module in module builder, and use a text field to store your entries. Add relationship with the contacts and accounts module

Answer (score 0):

Best approach will be to create your own SugarField.

This means creating the field first using the studio (probably a text field), and then using your own logic to store/retrieve/search that information from the DB.

This requirement ain't a simple one if you are just starting.

Here is the documentation [Docs](https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/support/tagme)

[Here a Ready to use Plugin](https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/support/tagme)